# c# timer not stopping

Tags: c#, timer

Timer starts with button1;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Timer function should work until i click STOP button

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Keyboard.KeyDown(Keys.D9);
   Thread.Sleep(1);
   Keyboard.KeyUp(Keys.D9);
   Thread.Sleep(1);
   Keyboard.KeyDown(Keys.D1);
   Thread.Sleep(1);
   Keyboard.KeyUp(Keys.D1);
}
```

Button2 is "stop" button but timer is not stopping until i close application , sometimes is stopping if i click more than five or ten but sometimes it  never stops

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("timer stop");
    }
```

Comment: Suspect you are keeping the thread too busy with your `timer1_Tick()` handler being fired every 1 millisecond (`timer1.Interval = 1`). Also the `Thread.Sleep()` holds on to the current thread preventing handling of other events like button2 clicks.

Comment: i can increase it up to 100 milicesond , doesn't matter bro , i cant stop it.

Comment: Why are you using Thread.Sleep() at every 1 ms interval ? There might be some better code replacement

Comment: i was need to a delay between keyDown() and keyUp() funcs , if i dont use it , our game can't handle this keypresses.

Comment: @OsmanErdi, you could use another system.Threading.timer for the keyraise that you can raise every 1 ms. Thread.Sleep(1) makes the thread jam for 1 ms, that I personally don't think is a good idea.

Comment: Hey i fixed it , it is very interesting , while timer is working , i clicked button2 to stop it , and if i clicked button2(stop button) and after that i press enter button on keyboard and it is stops :D why ? In order to this situation , i need to click button2 and press enter on keyboard to stop process

Comment: Glad that you solved it. . . ..

Comment: Hopefully not the `MessageBox.Show("timer stop");` requiring you to press enter :)

Comment: i remove message box but i still nedd to press enter after i clicked button it is so interesting but thank you brothers :)

Comment: I just had the same problem. I just found mine was because I was re-assigning the timer (called timer = new IntervalTimer) before stopping it. This means the original object is still alive until garbage collection gets rid of it (maybe with an attached event it won't). Could you be doing something similar? Mine happened when "Go" was clicked before the timer had fired.